как добавить новые модули в unity
у меня есть unity. и мне надо добавить новые модули для ios и android.
иcкал в интернете 1000 гайдов, но нигде нет ответа для unity 2022.3.49f1 и unity hub 3.9.1.


Устанавливай сборку через лончер, а не копируй сам, куда попало. Для этого нужно будет прочесть 0 гайдов в интернете.
